# how to Destructure the array with the different object having the same name value in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
const persons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Binod'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Harry'
  }
];


const [, , {name}] = persons;

console.log(name); // "Harry"
```

In this way, I can destructure only the single object, How can I destructure all the objects in a persons array????

Comment: It's possible by using `a:b` destructuring, but I don't see the point; you'd end up with hardcoded names like `name1`, `name2` etc.

Comment: Can you show the output you’re trying to get? Are you trying to get a separate variable for each object in the original array?